# How do I calculate the log odds of a quantitative dependent variable?

Tags: logistic, stata

I'm recreating [this study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0277953602001156) for a project, and they use as their dependent variable the log odds of mortality. I have the mortality variable, but it ranges from 584.9 to 973.3. How is this variable supposed to become a dummy which is either 0 or 1, and become this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mortality is probably expressed as number of deaths per some fixed number of people.

So when your mortality is, say, 800, it is not crude 800, it's 800 per (I supose) 100,000. So mortality is 800/100000 = 0.008, which gives
$$\log\left(\frac{mortality}{1-mortality}\right) = \log\left(\frac{0.008}{0.992}\right) \approx -4.8$$

Comment: Derylo thanks, this is certainly what the authors of the study calculated. However, would you know why they chose to express mortality as log odds instead of a simple linear equation? I ran scatter with the regular mortality variable and log odds mortality against another independent variable, and they're essentially the same, only that the log odds variable is bounded around -4. What value does this have?

Comment: Ask them :) I can only guess